# Sincronizar dados off-line com Phonegap

Tags: ajax, html5, apache-cordova

Surgiu uma situação que preciso sincronizar dados de um App porem nem sempre o dispositivo possui conectividade pois é usado por um vendedor na rua.
Quando possui conectividade ele salva direitinho via AJAX mas quando não possui eis o problema.

Uso como armazenamento do App o LocalStorage e banco remoto MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trabalhar com uma condicional. O cordova possui o plugin de conexão, conforme abaixo.

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

Toda vez que existir conectividade, mande para o servidor. Caso não, mande para o `locastorage`.

Depois vem a sincronização. Faça da seguinte forma(maneira mais simples);
Guarde um campo hora de atualização, e compare o do seu servidor com o do cliente e sincronize sempre com o mais recente.

Outra forma de fazer:
http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/05/simple-offline-data-synchronization-for-mobile-web-and-phonegap-applications/

**EDIT**

Achei esse plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync

Comment: hmmm... ta dando uma luz. No caso essa verificação deveria ser de tempo em tempo, na hora que pressionar o botao salvar ou antes de abrir o cadastro?

Comment: Pode ser de tempo em tempo, mas dependendo do numero de requisições ia sobrecarregar o servidor. Então cuidado

Comment: esse plugin ultimo que vc colocou me pareceu para sincronizar arquivos, procede?

Comment: Isso, eu nunca usei ele, mas desconfio que se você passar uma URL ele também funcionará. Caso não funcione, me avisa que eu edito a resposta